# MongoDb find documents based on values comparison of two fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm facing a challenge. Let's see documents first

```
{
  "FullName": "Sarajane Cazares",
  "FromTime": "2023-02-21T19:00:00Z",
  "ToTime": "2023-02-21T20:00:00Z",
  ...
}

{
  "FullName": "Marissa",
  "FromTime": "2023-02-21T20:00:00Z",
  "ToTime": "2023-02-21T21:00:00Z",
  ...
}
```

As you can see, ToTime of doc1 and FromTime of doc2 are same. I need to find all documents where ToTime and FromTime values are same.

Is it possible using MongoDB?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid, it's not possible via a simple match, but you can write a short aggregation pipeline for it. Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "ToTime",
      "foreignField": "FromTime",
      "as": "docs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$gt": [
          {
            "$size": "$docs"
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
])
```

In this pipeline, we perform a self-join on the collection, comparing `ToTime` and `FromTime` fields. Then we just, filter out the docs, where no docs having the same `ToTime` and `FromTime` are present.

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i8m8C5JLqb-)